# Build APK from command line behaves differently with Android Studio's [green] play button

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build an apk via [command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline) thru

```
gradlew assemleDebug
```

but I get the following error:

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131 contains a valid JDK installation.

However, when I use the green play button on my Android Studio, I can build and install my APK. Android Studio and I are using the same `gradlew` command, correct? But why the failure in command line?

There are numerous similar questions here in StackOverflow but none seem to describe the error I am experiencing.

Comment: is this your JAVA_HOME path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assign system path to java runtime enviroment. Install the Jdk in your computer and assign the path in system enviroment variable. Since JRE is only for runtime it will not compile the programm.

Your path : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131 
When you will install jdk here : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Since android have SDK kit which contains the above library you will not face any problem.

You can set java_home path through command line.

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"
```

and to verify just run this

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Let me know if this answer solved your query.

Comment: If you found this helpful plese upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that I solved the issue by assigning my environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with path to Android Studio's java installation, normally at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`.